# multiple tables select, Subquery returned more than 1 value. SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, multiple-tables

I have two tables:

Employees

```
id  | fullName   | birth      | speciality
1   | A A A      | 01/01/1980 | Manager
2   | B B B      | 01/01/1980 | Developer
3   | C C C      | 01/01/1980 | User
```

EmployeesStatus

```
ID  | status     | dateChange
1           | 1          | 01/01/2010
2           | 1          | 01/01/2013
3           | 1          | 01/01/2015
3           | 2          | 01/01/2016
```

and I want to seletect the following data

```
ID | Full name | Bith date | speciality | Date hired | Date fired
```

Result has to be:

```
ID | Full name    | Bith date   | speciality | Date hired | Date fired
1  | A A A        | 01/01/1980  | Manager    | 01/01/2010 | null
2  | B B B        | 01/01/1980  | Developer  | 01/01/2013 | null
3  | C C C        | 01/01/1980  | User       | 01/01/2015 | 01/01/2016
3  | C C C        |01/01/1980   | User       | 01/01/2017 | null
```

my code:

```
 SELECT Employees.id , Employees.fullName, Employees.birth, Employees.speciality,
(SELECT dateChange FROM EmployeesStatus WHERE status=1 AND id=Employees.id) datehired,
(SELECT dateChange FROM EmployeesStatus WHERE status=2 AND id=Employees.id) datefired FROM Employees
```

hase as result the following message:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Subquery returned more than 1
>   value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= ,
>
> > , >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Well, what do want to happen if more than 1 row is returned? Do you want just one of them? Or skip the sub-queries, do left join instead if you want all rows.

Comment: I believe the error message is self explanatory. You will get this error when any one of your sub-query returns more than one record. You can add `LIMIT` to restrict the sub-query to return one record or add proper filter condition to your sub-query

Comment: I'd also suggest not performing subqueries within your select statement, they're usually poor for performance. Try to move these into proper joins if you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to @scaisEdge answer:

```
SELECT 
    Employees.id,
    Employees.fullName,
    Employees.birth,
    Employees.speciality
    e1.dateChange as datehired, 
    MIN(e2.dateChange) as datefired
FROM Employees
INNER JOIN EmployeesStatus es1 on e1.status=1 AND e1.id=Employees.id
LEFT JOIN EmployeesStatus es2 on e2.status=2 AND e2.id=Employees.id
    AND e2.dateChange > e1.dateChange
GROUP BY Employees.id, 
    Employees.fullName,
    Employees.birth,
    Employees.speciality,
    e1.dateChange
```

Comment: as it is doesent works fullname, birth, speciality have to be included in the group by.but in this case we get only one (max) date of hiring and one (max) date of firing. if min, max and group by  deleteted we get the best until now result: first date hired-first date fired, first date hired-second date fired, second date hired- second date fired. if we eliminate the second of the three results we will have the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a join instead of an =  based on subquery

```
SELECT 
    Employees.id 
  , Employees.fullName
  , Employees.birth
  , Employees.speciality
  , e1.dateChange as datehired, e2.dateChange as datefired
FROM Employees
INNER JOIN EmployeesStatus es1 on e1.status=1 AND e1.id=Employees.id
LEFT JOIN EmployeesStatus es2 on e2.status=2 AND e2.id=Employees.id
```

Or you could use in clause instead of =  on  subquery

Comment: Why not two left join's?

Comment: very close to desired result, the only problem is that in case of two hirings the second line will have in date fired field the first firing , not null

Comment: also if there is second date of firing we will get all the possible combinations of the 2x2 dates

Comment: I think that an employess  id is hired  and fired one time  .. you should change the employee id

Comment: @scaisEdge I tried some versions wth in but dont have success. any specific suggestion?

Comment: when hire  an employee you should ceate a new id using an auto increment column for employees.ID   when you insert  a name (new or not) you have a new id so you can avoid the problem of multi hiring and multi firing... anyway seem you have akready solved ..

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
SELECT E.ID,E.FULLNAME,E.BIRTH,E.SPECIALITY,ED.DATE_HIRED,ED.DATE_FIRED
FROM EMPLOYEES E,
(SELECT     ID,
        MAX(CASE WHEN STATUS=1 THEN DATECHANGE ELSE NULL END)DATE_HIRED,
        MAX(CASE WHEN STATUS=2 THEN DATECHANGE ELSE NULL END)DATE_FIRED
FROM EMPLOYEESSTATUS
GROUP BY ID)ED
WHERE E.ID=ED.ID
```

This query will be faster in term of performance and will give you same result.

Comment: Query given Wrong ouput

Comment: this code returns only the last on date of hiring. if the first max is changed in min it returns the first.

Comment: @PoLee assumption is one employee will have one hire date and one fire data only. Correct me if it is not true? How come employee fired multiple time?

Comment: @jarlhsorry I have not ran on DB. can you let me know what syntax error? I am not able to figure out.

Comment: @Bhavesh Ghodasara  an employee can be hired and fired multiple times.No syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 SELECT e.id , 
        e.fullName,
        e.birth,
        e.speciality,   
        CASE WHEN t1.status = 1 then max(t1.dateChange) else null end as "Date Hired",
        CASE WHEN t2.status = 2 then max(t2.dateChange) else null end as "Date Fired",
    FROM Employees e
    LEFT JOIN EmployeesStatus t1 on t1.id = e.id and t1.status = 1
    LEFT JOIN EmployeesStatus t2 on t2.id = e.id and t1.status = 2
```

Hope this works..